# R- from columns to rows without taking the header

Tags: r, rows, data-cleaning

I have 8 variables per company, with a total of 25 companies. However, i don't need to make any distinction between these companies. If you look at the example: I need to have AH and JUMBO in one column, the same for AHQ1 and JUMBOQ1, and for both Q2s. In this way i don't have 6 columns, but just 3 and twice as much observations in these rows. The title of the column can stay AH, AHQ1, and AHQ2.

Thanks in advance for any tips!!

Example of data:

```
df <- data.frame("ID" = c(1,1,2,2,2,2), "Year" = c(2012, 2015,2012,2013,2015,2016), 
"AH" = c(1, NA, 1,1,1,1), "AHQ1" = c(8, NA,7,8,9,10),
             "AHQ2" = c(10,NA,7,8,5,2),"JUMBO" = c(NA,NA,1,1,1,NA), 
"JUMBOQ1" = c(NA,NA,8,9,7,NA), "JUMBOQ2"= c(NA,NA,10,9,7,NA))
```

Comment: Output of : dput(head(df)) >>


structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), Year = c(2012, 2015, 
2012, 2013, 2015, 2016), AH = c(1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1), AHQ1 = c(8, 
NA, 7, 8, 9, 10), AHQ2 = c(10, NA, 7, 8, 5, 2), JUMBO = c(NA, 
NA, 1, 1, 1, NA), JUMBOQ1 = c(NA, NA, 8, 9, 7, NA), JUMBOQ2 = c(NA, 
NA, 10, 9, 7, NA)), .Names = c("ID", "Year", "AH", "AHQ1", "AHQ2", 
"JUMBO", "JUMBOQ1", "JUMBOQ2"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: you should add that to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
temp <- cbind(df[1:2], df[6:8])
names(temp) <- names(df[1:5])

df2 <- rbind(df[1:5], temp)

> df2
   ID Year AH AHQ1 AHQ2
1   1 2012  1    8   10
2   1 2015 NA   NA   NA
3   2 2012  1    7    7
4   2 2013  1    8    8
5   2 2015  1    9    5
6   2 2016  1   10    2
7   1 2012 NA   NA   NA
8   1 2015 NA   NA   NA
9   2 2012  1    8   10
10  2 2013  1    9    9
11  2 2015  1    7    7
12  2 2016 NA   NA   NA
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes exactly, i think i can use this code for my whole dataset: 5000 observations and 25 variables, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. If this answers the question well enough, feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: Hello LAP, you solved the question but i tried it with a new dataset with 1 added variable and i get the following error: Warning message:
In data.table::data.table(...) :
  Item 2 is of size 9 but maximum size is 13 (recycled leaving remainder of 4 items)

Any suggestions how i can solve this?

Comment: Have you edited the code to account for the different number of columns?

Comment: Hello, it was because I imported the dataset via excel, instead of .csv. Thank you for you answer!